# How to add table of contents into title page in itext7 with c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I want to insert a TOC in a `Cell` on my title page. I need to generate the content first, before I know what the data of the TOC is. But, when I add content to the cell, it just stays blank in the rendered Pdf.

I generate the title page including the `Cell tocArea` in `GenerateTitlePage()`, populate the List `toc` in `GenerateContentPages()` and then try to fill the `tocArea` in `FillTOC()`.

```
namespace ProductTest
{
    internal class ProductDocument
    {
        // class variables omitted

        List<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>> toc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>>();

        public void CreatePdf()
        {
            // general setup
            string filename = "ProductTest.pdf";

            PdfDocument bgPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(templateLocation));
            PdfPage bgPage = bgPdf.GetPage(1);

            PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4.Rotate();

            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(filename));
            pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new HeaderFooterEventHandler(pdf));

            Document doc = new Document(pdf, pageSize, false);
            DocumentRenderer renderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc, false);
            doc.SetRenderer(renderer);

            doc.SetMargins(40, 6, 30, 6);

            Cell tocArea = new Cell().SetBorder(null);

            CreateTitlePage(doc, pageSize, bgPage, tocArea);

            CreateContentPages(doc, pageSize);

            FillTOC(doc, tocArea);

            bgPdf.Close();
            doc.Close();

            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(filename) { UseShellExecute = true });
        }

        private void CreateContentPages(Document doc, PageSize pageSize)
        {
           PdfDocument pdf = doc.GetPdfDocument();
           PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage(pageSize);
           
           // set up columns
           float horizontalOffset = 20;
           float verticalOffset = 60;
           float gap = 50;
           float columnWidth = (pageSize.GetWidth() - 2 * horizontalOffset - gap) / 2;
           float columnHeight = pageSize.GetHeight() - 2 * verticalOffset;

           Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[]
           {
               new Rectangle(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, columnWidth, columnHeight),
               new Rectangle(horizontalOffset + columnWidth + gap, verticalOffset, columnWidth, columnHeight)
           };

           doc.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, false, columns));
           doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));

           // Content is created here and toc populated
           // omitted for brevity
        }

        private void CreateTitlePage(Document doc, PageSize pageSize, PdfPage bgPage, Cell tocArea)
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = doc.GetPdfDocument();
            PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage(pageSize);
            Rectangle orig = bgPage.GetPageSizeWithRotation();
            doc.SetRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(doc));
            doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));

            // copy bg template
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
            AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(page.GetPageSize().GetWidth() / orig.GetWidth(), page.GetPageSize().GetHeight() / orig.GetHeight());
            canvas.ConcatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
            PdfFormXObject pageCopy = bgPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
            canvas.AddXObjectAt(pageCopy, 0, 0);

            // title page layout
            float infBoxWidth = 184;
            float titleContentWidth = page.GetPageSize().GetWidth() - doc.GetLeftMargin() - doc.GetRightMargin() - infBoxWidth;

            Table layout = new Table(new float[] { titleContentWidth, infBoxWidth });
            layout.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
                .AddCell(new Cell())
                .AddCell(new Cell())
                .SetMargins(24, 0, 0, 0);

            // left column
           // omitted for brevity
            headingText = "Content / Appendix";
            outline = CreateOutline(outline, pdf, headingText, headingText);
            leftColumn.Add(new Paragraph(headingText).AddStyle(heading2).SetDestination(headingText));

            // I add my placeholder cell here
            Table table = new Table(1).SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100)).SetMarginLeft(20).AddCell(tocArea);
            leftColumn.Add(table);

            // info box in right column
            // omitted for brevity

            doc.Add(layout);
        }

        // Here I try to fill the TOC with data. I get no errors, the cell is just blank in the rendered pdf
        private void FillTOC(Document doc, Cell tocArea)
        {
            // create table of contents
            int counter = 0;
            List<TabStop> tabStops = new List<TabStop>();
            DottedLine dottedLine = new DottedLine(1, 3);
            dottedLine.SetColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
            tabStops.Add(new TabStop(600, TabAlignment.RIGHT, dottedLine));
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> entry in toc)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, int> text = entry.Value;
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
                    .SetFont(arial)
                    .SetFontSize(9)
                    .SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE)
                    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)
                    .AddTabStops(tabStops)
                    .Add($"{++counter:d2} " + text.Key)
                    .Add(new Tab())
                    .Add(text.Value.ToString())
                    .SetAction(PdfAction.CreateGoTo(entry.Key));
                tocArea.Add(paragraph);
            }
            
        }

        // adds bookmarks to document
        private PdfOutline CreateOutline(PdfOutline outline, PdfDocument pdf, String title, String name)
        {
            // ommitted for brevity
        }

        // adds header and page number to pages
        private class HeaderFooterEventHandler : IEventHandler
        {
            // ommitted for brevity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi this page should get you on your way: https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/toc-as-first-page

Comment: I've already seen this approach, but it doesn't do what I want to do. The TOC there is on a separate page that is moved to the front. I've actually tried doing that with my title page, but then the page numbers in the TOC are wrong (0, 2, 2 instead of 2, 3, 3) and the pages are numbered 1, 1 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case anyone is interested, the suggested workflow is:

1. Create the PDF normally. (I excluded the title page in this case)
2. Figure out the page numbers from using the following sample in this Stack Overflow example: [Get the page number from document outline (bookmarks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716567/get-the-page-number-from-document-outline-bookmarks)
3. Store those page numbers somewhere
4. Create another PDF Document only this time you will know the page numbers of the outlines of the first PDF that you created. (Due to step 1 I added +1 to the page numbers to account for the title page)

With this approach there is no need to "go back" to the tocArea cell and modify it.